# How to run MySQL query results in numeric sequence?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a simple query where I would like a drop down box to show the results in numeric (integer) order.  Below is my query.

```
Select fv 
FROM fvqc
ORDER BY Value ASC
```

The results I get are like this -

```
1
13
14
18
2
23
27
3
30
31
```

What I would like to see is this -

```
 1
 2
 3
 13
 14
 18
 23
 27
 30
 31
```

Comment: you need to make sure your `Value` field is declared as `int()`  --  If it's `varchar()` -- That will be the expected result .. Notice al the **1**'s are first?

Comment: Thanks Zak, Yes, this column is Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast your values as numeric:

```
Select fv 
FROM fvqc
ORDER BY CAST(Value AS INT) ASC
```

Comment: I figured it was easy.  Thank you for your help.